# Is there a way I can import types using a generic parameter?

Tags: typescript, import

I have a function that works a bit like a wrapper for dynamic `import()` syntax:

```js
async importWrapper(url) {
  return await import(url);
}
```

Is there a way I can make this function use a return type based on the value of the `url` parameter?

I tried:

```
async function importWrapper<T extends string>(url: T) : Promise<typeof import(T)> {
    return await import(url);
}
```

but this gives an error:

```
Promise<typeof import(T)>
//                   ^^^--- TS1141 String literal expected
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcAsEsGdQO4HsBOBrWAuAUAQ1gJ4B2AxqAGYCup40SRoAJsbgLbQkAKuUAkqwAdU4ABSUUAG0yhY4FNCIBzAJShpnFEnawApgB5wBATqTlQ0QcJEAiAT0jXlAPlABvbKE%20gUO8OIa4CLjQ4OaWKKLiEsoA3NgAvtgk9LJhQhE6jACMoAC8oIHBocxEbBzcfOGitvaOcRbp4JlZMaAgoHZQAHScEjzkqKwVkNij2O0AQpShREgIoLyIuESh4EiglLoFoIo6RDryZHYobL4HOPjEZFQ0dAwNwgDqJwLGKHoAKqA6AB5NRIx4LJ5EonGJJNIPqp1JptPpDMZTGkrFCXO4vN5fP4CkEQsiIuDonFEkkUqFOpAALJIRiUCQ6PI4or48DPXCvA42Cl1bAU6m0%20mtdoAA2WBGFahEY2wv0arniQA)

Comment: Don't think there is a way to do this

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir 

Comment: Not currently possible, there's a feature request at [ms/TS#44663](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44636). Does that address the question? If so I could write up a (short!) answer. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz ah thanks! I've been trying to look for a feature request in the bug tracker but did not come across this one. Feel free to write up an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible, at least as of TypeScript 4.6, to express "`import` types" of a form like `import(T)` or `typeof import(T)`.

There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#44636](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44636) asking for support for something like this.  It is currently marked as "Awaiting Feedback" which means they would like to see what the community thinks before considering adopting such a feature.  So you might want to give the issue a  and comment on your use case; specifically why you need this and why existing workarounds don't suffice.

In any case I wouldn't expect to see anything implemented soon, or maybe even ever.  [A comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44636#issuecomment-863450514) by the dev lead for TS says that it would be a "heavy lift" to implement.  Oh well!

Comment: Thanks! I've posted my use case there. Not sure if they'll do much with it, only time will tell.