# Is there any way to type-safely wrap the import() function?

Tags: typescript, lazy-loading

TypeScript's `import()` expression allows to lazily load code at runtime. I can, for instance, call `await import('@my-app/a/b')` and receive an object that has exactly the members exported from the referenced source module.

This is type-safe; the TypeScript compiler knows at design time what members will be available on the returned object based on the path.

**Is there any way to wrap this `import()` expression and still get back the strongly-typed object?**

A use case would be so I can perform some standard operations on the returned object before it is handed back to the calling code.

For example:

Using the bare lazy-loaded module:

```
const module = await import('@my-app/a/b');
module.doSomething();
```

Using the lazy-loaded module only after standard operations have been done:

```
const module = await loadAndProcessModule('@my-app/a/b');
module.doSomething();
```

The question is how to implement, or at least declare, `loadAndProcessModule` without breaking type-safety.

Comment: Why not `await loadAndProcessModule(import("@my0app/a/b"))`? And no you can't really make it work otherwise.

Comment: @Kay: What is the return type of `loadAndProcessModule` in your example?

Comment: Whatever you want it to be? The point is, with this method, you have the *concrete* type of the imported module, and you can use that for whatever (hint: **generics**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in order to do this, you would need to be able to express `typeof import("module-specifier")` as a generic. e.g. your `loadAndProcessModule` function signature would need to look something like this:

```
function loadAndProcessModule<T extends string>(moduleSpecifier: T): typeof import(T) {
   // ...
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not possible in Typescript today - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71734854/is-there-a-way-i-can-import-types-using-a-generic-parameter) and [this open feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44636).